# Does ReSharper have a refactor to eliminate the closing html tag

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

Does ReSharper (or Visual Studio) have a refactoring where it can turn

```
<DxCheckBox @bind-Checked="@(((UserListModel)context.EditModel).EmailConfirmed)" 
    AllowIndeterminateState="false">
</DxCheckBox>
```

into:

```
<DxCheckBox @bind-Checked="@(((UserListModel)context.EditModel).EmailConfirmed)" 
    AllowIndeterminateState="false"/>
```